# Catching an SEH exception on HoloLens (native code compiled to UWP)

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I'm tring to catch SEH exception that thrown from c++ code (native) from a C# function on the HoloLens, which the native code compiled as UWP.

I'm using Visual Studio for this, an Interface Definition (IDL) file for generating a `.winmd` library which I can later link with the C# code without needing to use dll import or `extern "C"`

I compiled the native code with VS, and configured: `Enable C++ Exception` with `Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa)`

When I run the application on the HoloLens, the `index == 1` exception caught, the other ones cause the app to crash

I know that there is no much to do with catching those exceptions, and still I would like to catch them. Same as I can catch them in c++ code (by using `catch (...)`) or as I could with .Net versions before 4.0v.

Anyone have an idea why I can't catch these exceptions?

Let's say that this is the native funcion:

```cpp
// h file
namespace NativeSEHException
{
   void Foo(int index);
}

// cpp file
#include "NativeSEHException.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void NativeSEHException::Foo(int index)
{
    static int i = index; // first call will be with index == 0
    if (index == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "throw std::exception\n";
            throw std::bad_exception();
            // This section works, since it's not an SEH exception
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "divide by zero\n";
            int y = 8 / i;
            std::cout << y << '\n';
        }
        else if (index == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Access nullptr\n";
            int* p = nullptr;
            int y = 8 + *p;
            std::cout << y << '\n;
        }
        else if (index == 3)
        {
            std::cout << "access empty cv::Mat\n";
            cv::Mat mat;
            std::cout << mat.at<float>(0, 3) << '\n';
        }
        else if (index == 4)
        {
            std::cout << "vector out of range access\n";
            std::vector<float> v;
            std::cout << v[500000] << '\n';
        }
}
```

This is my C# function:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [SecurityCritical]
    public void ExceptionCatcher()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                NativeSEHException.Foo(i);
            }
            catch (SEHException e)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Caught a SEH exception: {e}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Caught a general Exception: {e}");
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log($"Caught something else");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another name for "SEH exception" seems to be "undefined behavior". And yet another name is "demons flying out of your nose". The program is in an undeterminate, unstable state, and one cannot reasonably expect any C++ library function or any data structure in the program to be in a usable state. So, even though you can use your low-level operating system functions to catch this exception, there's nothing useful you can do, at this point, with any expectation of reliable results. Instead of catching the exception, the correct fix is to figure out the bug that threw it, and fix the bug.

Comment: An access violation is not an SEH. Access violations cannot be caught normally

Comment: @SamVarshavchik SEH is a perfectly reasonable exception handling mechanism. It's not designed to work with AVs though, and can be difficult to marshal across a PInvoke boundary properly

Comment: I want to exit the app gracefully instead of crashing.. It is possible to catch them in c++ by using `catch (...)` also it was possible with .Net versions before 4.0